# Trimming the edge of a picture (not resizing)

Tags: edit-mode

this might be something I can't do in blender. I know what to do in photoshop etc but i was hoping there was a quick way around having to do that.
I have an imported image i want to use on the side of a box , its just s bit big and i want to trim the edges so it fits nice.
in the pic the left image is the box with knobs etc that i want the image cropped in size to fit. The right image is just as a referene to what it looks like on its own.
I want to crop the black edge around it.
Possible?[image]

Thanks.

Comment: do you mean scale the picture so that now the edge is white? or paint in white? In the first case, scale the UV of the object in the UV Editor. In the second case you can paint the image in the Image Editor (or even in the 3D view in Texture Paint mode)

Comment: Hey Moonboots, see how the left one has a box under it? I want to trim the excess black around the outside of the picture so it fits flush with the box underneath. The edge of the pic is the interior white box. The black around the edge is just background and I want to get rid of it.
THANKS.